# check content update javascript Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.3.2, infinte-scroll

I have changed content to next page in category page in magento by
https://infiniteajaxscroll.com/docs/methods.html

I try to check content of list update by this function:

```
$('.category-products .products.list').change(function () {
    console.log('list update');
});
```

It doesn't work for me.

Comment: I found the solution:

$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', ".products.list", function() {


    ...

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a free extension available for infinite scroll. Please take reference from the code of this extension. Please find the repo of extension below:

https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento2-InfiniteScroll

Comment: Thank you. But the issue, We must call back lazy load

Comment: The above extension call it by this line:  next: '<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getSelector('next')); ?>', in js.phtml